# Why Website with Retina-ready using original size image in PC?

Tags: html, css, templates, retina-display

Some Mobile website with Retina-ready using twice the size of image to get finer quality,

and using the original size of image in PC.

I don't understand why don't directly use twice the size of image in every device,

because Computers isn't so urgent need to save network traffic.

Prepare two different sizes of the picture is too spend time....

It is a Blind Spot ? or I am wrong ?..

=============================================================

Extra Content - 2013-07-10 :

The only questions is "they use original size image in PC, so why not just use twice size image in PC?"
it make same effect in Retina-ready, why PC need original size, PC didn't need ,right?

Comment: You mean why don't they blow up all images to twice their normal size on normal (96 DPI) computer monitors?

Comment: yes, don't use original size in PC, why not? It make same effect,but different spend time.

Comment: Provided that they want images with Retina-ready effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, the question is why don't websites use the same hi-res picture that they use for Retina displays on lower DPI monitors as well.

Then my reaction is, why should they?

- A picture twice the size in pixels takes up four times the amount of bytes. That's not just bandwidth, but also memory in the client's computer
- You don't gain anything in quality. If anything, the quality on screen decreases, if the browser's resize ability is not of the highest standard (read: if they optimise for speed rather than quality)
- In addition, there are browsers that suffer a noticeable performance hit when you scroll up and down on a page with many resized images
- Lastly, for the webdeveloper, creating smaller copies of the pictures before deploying them on the web server doesn't take up that much time. There are automated utilities that can do that, on the press of a button.